# Adding menu to In E4 MWindow

Tags: eclipse, e4

In our Eclipse E4 (pure e4)  application I have to open a new window and show some views in a new window (which is completely different from the main window). In the new window I am trying to add menu (File->Import) pro-grammatically. I have written the below code but the new window is not showing the menus. Anything I am missing?

`

```
MTrimmedWindow window = MBasicFactory.INSTANCE.createTrimmedWindow();
....

MMenu menuBar = MenuFactoryImpl.eINSTANCE.createMenu();
menuBar.setLabel("Test");
window.setMainMenu(menuBar);

MMenu fileMenu = MenuFactoryImpl.eINSTANCE.createMenu();
fileMenu.setElementId("file");
fileMenu.setLabel("File");
menuBar.getChildren().add(fileMenu);

MMenuItem item1 = MenuFactoryImpl.eINSTANCE.createDirectMenuItem();
item1.setElementId("item1");
item1.setLabel("item1");
fileMenu.getChildren().add(item1);`
```

Comment: Does it have to be programmatic? It is much easier to design the window in the Application.e4xmi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add the window to the application children until after you have created and setup the main menu (and anything else you want to have in the window).

When you add the window to the application child list it is rendered immediately. So if you have not set the main menu at that point it will not be shown.

If your window design is fixed you can avoid all this code by designing the window in the Application.e4xmi. Just turn off the 'to be rendered' flag so it is not show initially and then do:

```java
MTrimmedWindow window = (MTrimmedWindow)modelService.find("window id", app);

window.setToBeRendered(true);
```

to show the window.

Comment: It worked. Actually when I was typing  the question I thought U will answer this :) ,,I was searching you in google plus so that I can ask you this question directly . Thanks alot. Will try directly adding in Application.e4xmi. the second window

Comment: 1st, It worked in Application.e4xmi. also. Thanks for that. 2nd  In our application the number of windows created will be depending on user clicks, I think it is better I create dynamic windows than creating though Application.e4xmi. I think it is better I create programmatically.